# Printing rows from table but getting error?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

Here is my code. I have no problem printing out one column from a a table but can't seem to get it right in printing two.

```
fc = "C:\Users\Brett\Desktop\lesson_5\Lesson5_Data\Lesson5_Data\COUNTIES.shp"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,["COUNTY","Joint_Count"]) as Cursor:
                       for row in Cursor:
                           print "COUNTY = {0}".format(row[0])
```

Comment: `.getValue()` needs to be called multiple times for each field. Alternatively, you can use [data access cursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) where you can pass in multiple fields and get their values as tuples.

Comment: What error are you getting? These are key to debugging.  For example I would expect an IndentationError from the code snippet that you have presented.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brett/Desktop/Hw_5.py", line 19, in <module>
    row.getValue("Join_Count")))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 1100, in getValue
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.GetValue(*gp_fixargs(args)))
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.

Comment: That error, which should have been presented as an [edit] to your question, comes from line 19 but the code you have presented only has 5 lines.  Please take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  Your title and comment talk about an error but your question body makes no mention of it.  The [Tour] leads to advice like http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question which should help you improve your question.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Paul's comment, you could call the `.getValue()` method for each of your desired fields, for each row generated by the cursor object. Your code is almost there, it just needs a fix on the looping constructs:

```
fc = r"C:\Users\Brett\Desktop\lesson_5\Lesson5_Data\Lesson5_Data\COUNTIES.shp"
field_list = ["COUNTY", "Joint_Count"]
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    for fld in field_list:
        print(row.getValue(fld))
```

EDIT: Following the edit to the question, we can still apply a similar approach to solve the problem for the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` used in the updated question:

```
fc = r"C:\Users\Brett\Desktop\lesson_5\Lesson5_Data\Lesson5_Data\COUNTIES.shp"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["COUNTY","Joint_Count"]) as Cursor:
    for row in Cursor:
        print("COUNTY = {0}".format(row[0]))
        print("Join_Count = {0}".format(row[1]))
```

Comment: +1. BTW you don't need to cast to `str` as `.format()` will handle that for you as needed.

Comment: Thanks @Paul - I totally did not know about that feature of `.format()` - Learnin' stuff every day. Thanks!